# SpringBatch & ORA-01792: maximum number of columns in a table or view is 1000

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, spring-batch

I have developed a spring batch application which is reading data from 6 oracle tables and processing it. The problem is that reading more than 1000 columns of data. This was manually solved by executing `ALTER session SET "_fix_control"='17376322:OFF';` command at SQL Side but I am unable execute this command spring batch code side. Can any one help on how to execute `ALTER session SET "_fix_control"='17376322:OFF'` command using spring batch.

I have to execute "ALTER session SET "_fix_control"='17376322:OFF'" command before executing select statement given below:

```
<batch:job id="extract">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="ItemReader"
                    processor="Processor" writer="ItemWriter"
                    commit-interval="1">
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job> 
<bean id="ItemReader"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sql">
            <value>
            <![CDATA[
 SELECT 
[1000+ Columns]
FROM #{jobParameters[table1]} D 
left join #{jobParameters[table2}  A on D.xyz=A.xyz
left join #{jobParameters[table3]} D2 on D.xyz=D2.xyz
left join #{jobParameters[table4]} A2 on D.xyz = A2.xyz
left join #{jobParameters[table5]} fed on D.xyz=fed.xyz
left join #{jobParameters[table6]} g on d.xyz=g.xyz
left join #{jobParameters[table7]} l on d.xyz=l.xyz

            ]]>
            </value>
        </property>

        <property name="rowMapper">
            <bean class="XXX.DataRowMapper" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: you can set that alter session statement on the dataSource bean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set it on the data source...

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="${driverClassName}" />
<property name="url" value="${datasource.url}" />
<property name="username" value="#" />
<property name="password" value="#" />
<property name="connectionInitSqls" value="${datasource.initsql}" />
</bean>
```

and then in your properties...

```
datasource.initsql=ALTER session SET "_fix_control"='17376322:OFF
```

Comment: I am using as follow then how to declare connectionInitSqls? <bean id="dataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
   <property name="url" value="#" /> 
  <property name="username" value="#" />
  <property name="password" value="#" />
 </bean>

Answer (score 3):

You could add a logon trigger on the database that issues the set command

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER YOUR_DB_USER.SET_FIX_CONTROL_ON_LOGON
AFTER LOGON ON YOUR_DB_USER..SCHEMA
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER session SET "_fix_control"=''17376322:OFF'''; 
END;
```